# ObjectListView AlternateRowBackColor & FormatCell Event

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I've got a DataListView that has has its source from a DataTable.

When I set the AlternateRowBackColor, and also UseAlternatingBackColors to true, I did not get any change in the view itself.

Also, I've got this FormatCell event that changes the SubItem's ForeColor if it is smaller than a certain value, but the color only changes when i hover across that row. it is not being fired at load.

```
if (e.Column.AspectName != "Column1")
{
    if (float.Parse(e.CellValue.ToString()) < 2.0,)
    {
        e.SubItem.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
   }
}
```

Anyone know what is the problem behind these?

Comment: Hi Grant, this is a winform, that event is FormatCell, part of DataListView from ObjectListView lib.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `AlternateRowBackColor` and `UseAlternatingBackColors` are set before setting the `DataSource`.

Check that `UseCellFormatEvents` is set to `true`.

If you know that the cell is going to hold a float, then reparsing it is pointless.

```
if (((float)e.CellValue) < 2.0f) ...
```

would work better

Comment: Hi Grammarian! I am not able to get the AlternateBackColor working, I've recreated the whole thing programmatically instead of using the IDE. Why is it that when i use code, after adding the datatable into the datasource, my column size got resetted? Furthermore The columns will not automatically resize themselves anymore.